# Alternative to `any` that returns the last evaluated object?

Tags: python

I just wrote a bit of code where I wanted to do:

```
def foo(container)
    return any((some_obj.attr <= 0 for some_obj in container))
```

where `foo` would return the first `some_obj` where `some_obj.attr` is zero or less. The alternative, I suppose, would be

```
def foo(container):
    return next((some_obj for some_obj in container if some_obj.attr <= 0), False)
```

but that feels very hacky.

I ended up writing it out, but I don't like how deeply nested it got.

```
def foo(container):
    for some_obj in container:
        if some_obj.attr <= 0:
            return some_obj
    return False
```

To clarify: `container` in this case is likely no more than 6 objects (and often 2 objects), though a general case is more useful. I'm also trying to optimize for ease of reading, not for performance.

Is there some better construct than this?

Comment: I'd go with an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: @user2357112 that's what I ended up doing. It seemed dangerously close to Arrow Of Doom. I included that case in my question, though.

Comment: This is no more deeply nested than the "equivalent to" code documented for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) itself.

Comment: The `next` certainly isn't hacky, maybe it doesn't appear so elegant but it's a viable option

Comment: The two options you have already are both perfectly readable in my opinion  :)

Comment: They all look perfectly fine to me and they are all perfectly readable. If you'd to make a choice, I'd base it on performance. Why don't you time it for your typical use case? If I'd to go with "aesthetics", I'd say that the first option would be my favorite one, some people may call it the most "pythonic" solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The docs for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) explain that it's equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

So, I don't think your code is too deeply nested if it has exactly the same structure as code that's used to illustrate the functionality of `any` itself.

Still, I would probably wrap this up in a function:

```
def first(iterable, predicate):
    for element in iterable:
        if predicate(element):
            return element
    return False
```

So now you can do this:

```
def foo(container):
    return first(container, lambda obj: obj.attr <= 0)
```

Or, alternatively, just use a generator expression, and pass it to the two-argument [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), as you're already doing:

```
def foo(container):
    return next((obj for obj in container if obj.attr <= 0), False)
```

That has the same "depth", it's just all horizontal instead of vertical.

Or, maybe, pull out the genexpr and name it:

```
def foo(container):
    nonpositives = (obj for obj in container if obj.attr <= 0)
    return next(nonpositives, False)
```

How would you choose between them? I think if the predicate is too complicated to read as a `lambda` but not complicated enough to be worth abstracting out into an out-of-line function, I'd go with the genexpr. Otherwise, the wrapper function. But it's really a matter of taste.

Comment: Well I was really hoping someone would come in and say "Oh, didn't you know you can do `or *container`?

Comment: @AdamSmith: Honestly, I think if `lambda` were more light-weight (in terms of visibility/obtrusiveness), nobody would have a problem with functions like `first` or the builtin `filter` or `itertools.takewhile` in the first place, and we wouldn't have had to borrow comprehensions from Haskell. But Guido has already declared that "a problem not worth solving, except as an intellectual exercise", so… oh well, on those occasionally where you need to go just a little beyond what comprehensions make trivial, there's a bit of a jump in readability.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and give the checkmark here, if only because it has the best breakdown of when and why you'd choose different approaches.

Comment: @abarnert Boo, zero doesn't belong to "negatives".

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Thanks. That's always a risk in coming up with a "meaningful" name; you it can have the wrong meaning. :) Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

`next(filter` should do it, and here's a funny way to test `<= 0`:

```
>>> next(filter((0).__ge__, [3,2,1,-1,-2]), False)
-1
```

Ha, even tricker:

```
>>> next(filter(0..__ge__, [3,2,1,-1,-2]), False)
-1
```

Or, as abarnert pointed out:

```
>>> next(filter(0 .__ge__, [3,2,1,-1,-2]), False)
-1
```

Comment: That's nice, but try working that with an attribute of an object instead of just numbers

Comment: @jamylak just means it removes the ugly `int(0).__ge__` hack and turns it into a lambda. This is still valid :P

Comment: @AdamSmith Hmm, that was a hack? Is it better now that I removed the `int`?

Comment: The problem is that he's testing `obj.attr <= 0`, not just `obj <= 0`.

Comment: Of course you can do `compose(attrgetter('attr'), (0).__ge__)`… But at that point you have to ask yourself why you're using Python instead of Haskell, which would actually make that readable.

Comment: I can't imagine reading that code and knowing explicitly what it did. `lambda o: o.attr <= 0` is a more obvious filter. That said: leave it because it's kinda cool :)

Comment: @abarnert Oooh, now I get it. Darn. Wouldn't have happened if the OP had provided an example input so I hadn't made one up.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ah, sorry about that. I *did* put `some_obj.attr <= 0` in every one of my examples ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah, I'd usually do a lambda as well, it's certainly more usual and flexible. But I also love the unusual and show people stuff that they might not have seen before :-)

Comment: @AdamSmith: In Python-Haskell-hybrid syntax, the `compose` would be something like `(<= 0) @ (.attr)`, which I think is a lot nicer… but YMMV.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, I see it now, I had just overlooked it, sorry. Many of the questions posted here contain horrible code and I tend to disregard it and just focus on the given text/input/output. That bit me here, as there was no input/output and the code was good. It's also 6:24am and I should go to bed :-P

Comment: @AdamSmith Wow, I found a further improvement, see the answer again. Now I guess Python doesn't like `0.__ge__` because it interprets the `.` as part of a float, and `0.` is a float and then the second `.` is unambiguously for a method.

Comment: @abarnert Can you tell whether my explanation for `0..__ge__` in the comment right above this one is correct? I don't know much Python internals and can only guess.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: You're right about `0..__ge__` being valid because it's unambiguously a float literal followed by an attribution. I'm not use if `0.__ge__` is a `SyntaxError` because it's ambiguous, or because it was explicitly designed to be illegal to avoid that ambiguity, but either way, the basic idea is that `0.__ge__` could be a method on `0` or garbage following `0.`, as you said. You can also just use `0 .__ge__`, which is unambiguously the same as `(0).__ge__` and one char shorter, but a lot less readable.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Also, IIRC, in 2.x, `int.__ge__` doesn't exist (`>=` falls back to `__cmp__`), but `float.__ge__` does (because `NaN` is actually why `__ge__` and friends were added in the first place), so your `0..` hack has the advantage of making your code work in 2.x as well.

Comment: @abarnert Wow, a space to separate. I'm loving it! :-) Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, to extend [Stefan Pochmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364476/908494) to handle `obj.attr <= 0`, still without needing a lambda:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from functional import compose

next(filter(compose(0..__ge__, attrgetter('attr')), [3, 2, 1, -1, -2]), False)
```

If you don't have the `functional` module (which you probably don't, because the version on PyPI hasn't worked since Python 2.4 or so…) and don't want to search for a modern replacement, you can write `compose` yourself (and slightly better):

```
def compose(f, g):
    @functools.wraps(f):
    def wrapper(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return wrapper
```

---

About once/year, there's a proposal to add `compose` to the stdlib, and maybe even give it an infix operator. With [`@` being added for matrix multiplication](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), you can guess the latest proposal.<sup>*</sup> So, if that happens (which it probably won't), you can do this:

```
from operator import attrgetter

next(filter(0..__ge__ @ attrgetter('attr'), [3, 2, 1, -1, -2]), False)
```

Now the only thing we need is Haskell-style [operator sectioning](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/05/operator-sectioning-for-python.html) so we can get rid of the bound method, the `..` hack, and the need for an `attrgetter` function (assuming you consider dot-attribution an operator, which it really isn't, but let's pretend…). Then:

```
next(filter((<= 0) @ (.attr), [3, 2, 1, -1, -2]), False)
```

---

<sub>* In fact, it was proposed, twice, during the initial PEP 465 discussion, which is why the PEP mentions, "During discussions of this PEP, a similar suggestion was made to define `@` as a general purpose function composition operator, and this suffers from the same problem; `functools.compose` isn't even useful enough to exist."</sub>